# Memory management of objects in java

Tags: java, object, memory, memory-management, reference

I'm reading this book on data structures and it covers memory management and orphaned objects in Java.The textbook says the following:

> For example, consider the three assignment statements in the figure at
>   left. After the third assignment statement, not only do *a* and *b* refer
>   to the same Date object (1/1/2011), but also there is no longer a
>   reference to the Date object that was created and used to initialize
>   *b*. The only reference to that object was in the variable *b*, and this
>   reference was overwritten by the assignment, so there is no way to
>   refer to the object again. Such an object is said to be orphaned.

Code:

```
Date a=new Date(12, 31, 1999);
Date b=new Date(1, 1, 2011);
b=a;
```

Is that statement true? Shouldn't the reference of a (the memory location of object `Date(12, 31, 1999)` be what the reference of b be? This seems like one huge error but there is even a picture showing memory block for 12, 31, 1999 being the orphaned object.

Picture:
http://imageshack.us/f/818/3tkx.jpg/

Comment: I see what you mean. The code should read `a = b;` for there statement to be true.

Comment: Yeah so is that statement false from the book?

Comment: Date(1, 1, 2011) will be orphaned since link b is pointing to Date(12, 31, 1999)

Comment: What book is this by the way?

Comment: See my answer. It's most probably an editorial error. Maybe you can find and check an errata.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Algorithms-4th-Edition-Robert-Sedgewick/dp/032157351X

Comment: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/errata/errata-printing1.php
=> Chapter 1, p. 104
It's reported and fixed for future versions.

Comment: I see, thank you i will check errata from now on :)

Comment: They fixed it the way I suggested ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In java you always assign something on the **right** to a reference to the **left**.

So you statements say something like this:

1. Assign the new `Date` object `Date(12, 31, 1999)` to the variable `a`
2. Assign the new `Date` object `Date(91, 1, 2011)` to the variable `b`
3. Assign the reference of variable `a` to variable `b`.

So it looks like this if I follow those steps:

1. `a` ->  `Date(12, 31, 1999)`
2. `a` ->  `Date(12, 31, 1999)`
   `b` ->  `Date(1, 1, 2011)`
3. `a` ->  `Date(12, 31, 1999)`
   `b` ->  `Date(12, 31, 1999)`

Please note that after this assignment the original object of `Date(1, 1, 2011)` is no longer referenced since you cannot reach it from your application. Its original referencing variable `b` is overwritten and now the object `Date(12, 31, 1999)` is referenced from both `a` and `b`. `Date(91, 1, 2011)` is *orphaned* and ready to be garbage collected.

*Imagine this as if you were holding a sword and an axe. First you pick up a sword. Then you pick up the axe. After that you drop the sword and drag the axe you still have in your hand with both hands. After that you do not hold the sword you dropped (it is lost).*

**Edit: This is an error if you tell the author of the book he will be grateful.**

Comment: +1 for an example with swords! :-D
Maybe you should replace the second sword with a stick to avoid confusion while reading.

Answer (score 2):

The `b=a` statement discards the current value of `b`, and since there are no other references to the date object that was called b, yes, the b date is orphaned.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the orphaned object is the one which was pointed to by `b`, which is `Date(1, 1, 2011)`. If the picture shows otherwise, then it is definitely wrong.

```
a --> 31.12.1999     b --> 1.1.2011

                 |
                \ /

a --> 31.12.1999 <-- b     1.1.2011 (orphaned!)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep, the

> (1/1/2011)

in the text is wrong. **It's most probable a editorial error.** Apart from that everything else is correct. b is overwritten with the content of a, which is Date(12, 31, 1999). Therefore both variables point to Date(12, 31, 1999) and Date(1, 1, 2011) is orphaned and can be garbage collected.

Maybe you should check an errata of your book. :-)

Comment: I will do that next time, ty

Answer (score 2):

Lets say `a`'s referring to Date object stored at memory location `123`.
Going by same logic, lets say `b`'s referring to Date object stored at memory location `546`.(New object new location).

Now when you do `b = a`. `b`'s referring to `Object @ 123`. `546` is no longer accessible and can be GC'ed anytime.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is **false** (the explanation is fine, but he confuses the objects)

- The object created with `new Date(12, 31, 1999)` is referenced two times, by `a` and `b`
- The object created with `new Date(91, 1, 2011)` is not referenced by anyone else after the `b=a` assigment, so it will be deleted from memory